# Swagger describe response when endpoint returns enum

Tags: c#, enums, asp.net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an endpoint in my ASP.NET Core Web API marked with the following tag `[ProducesResponseType(typeof(SomeEnum), 200)]`. Where `SomeEnum` is an enumeration with two or more values. I use Swagger for generating documentation. The problem comes when I run the project and navigate to the api docs page. For this endpoint the only docs I have is:

[image]

But I want to have something like this:
[image]

Broadly speaking, I want my enums to have description of the values they can take.

This is my swagger configuration:

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "API", Version = "v1" });

                var fileName = this.GetType().GetTypeInfo().Module.Name.Replace(".dll", ".xml");

                c.IncludeXmlComments(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, fileName));

            c.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();

            c.OperationFilter<AddAuthorizationHeader>();
        });
```

Example for an enum definition to be added:

```
public enum SomeSampleEnum 
{
  Success,
  Fail,
  OperationResult
}
```

Comment: Can you add your enum definition too?

Comment: Added to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your enum to:

```
public enum SomeSampleEnum 
{
  Success = 1,
  Fail = 2,
  OperationResult = 3
}
```

In my case that worked.
You might need to change some other code too...

Comment: Does not work in my case. Maybe I am missing something in the configuration.

Comment: It's similar to my Config. The only thing that is different is, I'm using the enum as a property of a class.

Comment: Yes, as a property of a class it works, but it is interesting why it does not work when it is not a part of a class.